# Flat Maurer-Cartan connection iff flat Berry connection

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, connections

I am studying two connections on induced representation spaces $\text{Ind}_{H}^{G} \Gamma$, where $H \subseteq G$ are groups, and $\Gamma$ is an irrep of $H$.

1. The first is the canonical or $H$-connection, which is the projection of $G$'s Maurer-Cartan form into $H$'s Lie algebra. A [paper by Milnor](https://eudml.org/doc/139154) classifies all such flat connections in terms of monodromy groups $\pi_1(G/H)/\ker \rho$, induced by $\pi_1$-irreps $\rho$. These irreps determine the monodromy after a non-contractible closed path in the coset space.
2. The second is the [Berry connection](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9504116) (see [here](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/records/2pepc-k9f58) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1782) for mathematican description), $\langle a,\mu |\partial a,\nu\rangle$, for "position states" $|a,\mu\rangle$ of a particle on the induced-rep space, where $a \in G/H$, and $\mu,\nu$ index the irrep space of $\Gamma$. Here a position state moves in the coset space $G/H$, and obtains a holonomy (in physics: Berry phase or matrix) after a closed path that acts on the $\mu$ factor. The possible monodromies (physics: topological Berry phases or matrices) for non-contractible closed paths are classified by the monodromy group $H/\ker \Gamma$.

The two connections are related but not generally equal [[Eq. (4.2) here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9504116) or [here]](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(88)91294-4). For all examples I'm aware of, the connections are zero iff the two monodromy groups **match**. In other words, I see that both connections are flat for a given inducing $H$-irrep $\Gamma$ if there exists a $\pi_1$-irrep $\rho$ such that

$$
\frac{H}{\ker \Gamma} = \frac{\pi_1(G/H)}{\ker \rho}~.
$$

I was hoping someone could either prove this or provide a counterexample. Here are some examples:

- Both connections are flat and the monodromy is trivial for the sphere, $\text{Ind}_{U(1)}^{SU(2)} 0$, where $0$ is the trivial irrep of $U(1)$. The above equation holds since $H/\ker\Gamma = U(1)/U(1)$, $\pi_1$ is trivial, and its only (trivial) irrep can be picked to be $\rho$.
- Both connections are not flat and the monodromy is trivial for the sphere with a monopole of nonzero strength $\lambda$, $\text{Ind}_{U(1)}^{SU(2)} \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a non-trivial irrep of $U(1)$. Conjecture holds since $H/\ker \Gamma = U(1)/\mathbb{Z}_{|\lambda|} = U(1)$, $\pi_1$ is the same (i.e., trivial), and so it's impossible to find a $\rho$ that can fill in the above equation.
- Both connections are flat and the monodromy is nontrivial for the Poincare homology sphere with some inducing $A_5$-irrep $\Gamma$, $\text{Ind}^{SO(3)}_{A_5} \Gamma$. The above equation holds since $\pi_1 = 2A_5$, and so one can pick the $\pi_1$-irrep corresponding to $\Gamma$ under the double cover to be $\rho$.

Comment: We noticed the pattern when we calculated Berry connections for orientations of molecules in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.04572.